# How to add the toolbar in leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I want to add the leaflet toolbar like below in the MapContainer, would you please help ?

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3WR.png)]

```
<MapContainer
  id='mymap'
  center={[65, 300]}
  zoom={1}
  zoomControl={true}
  doubleClickZoom={false}
  attributionControl={false}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
  className="h-full w-full"
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', objectFit: 'cover' }}
>
  <ImageOverlay
    url={ImageURL}
    bounds={[[0, 0], [dimensions.width, dimensions.height]]}
  />
</MapContainer>
```

I tried everything ,nothing works!

Comment: What is the value of ImageURL?

Comment: const [ImageURL, setImageURL] = useState<string>("");

Comment: Would you please paste code and what is the error or what is exactly failing ?